# Gmail API read only property 403 forbidden error on iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I followed [this url](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift)

```
import GoogleAPIClientForREST
import GTMOAuth2
```

In view controller, I added a button to initiate the gmail api configuration

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnSyncGmail: UIButton! //button to configure Gmail API
```

I mentioned client id for oAuth here i commented hidden the client id in ******

```
private let kClientID = "*******************.apps.googleusercontent.com"
private let kRedirectURI = "com.googleusercontent.apps.***********************:/oauthredirect"

private let kKeychainItemName = "Sync Gmail"
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials by
// resetting the iOS simulator or uninstall the app.
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeGmailReadonly]

private let service = GTLRGmailService()
let output = UITextView()

// When the view loads, create necessary subviews
// and initialize the Gmail API service
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Construct a query and get a list of upcoming labels from the gmail API
func fetchLabels() {
    output.text = "Getting labels..."

    let query = GTLRGmailQuery_UsersLabelsList.query(withUserId: "me")
    service.executeQuery(query,
                         delegate: self,
                         didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
    )
}

// Display the labels in the UITextView
func displayResultWithTicket(ticket : GTLRServiceTicket,
                             finishedWithObject labelsResponse : GTLRGmail_ListLabelsResponse,
                              error : NSError?) {

    if let error = error {
        showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    var labelString = ""

    if (labelsResponse.labels?.count)! > 0 {
        labelString += "Labels:\n"
        for label in labelsResponse.labels! {
            labelString += "\(label.name!)\n"
        }
    } else {
        labelString = "No labels found."
    }

    output.text = labelString

}


// Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Gmail API
private func createAuthController() -> GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch {
    let scopeString = scopes.joined(separator: " ")
    return GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(
        scope: scopeString,
        clientID: kClientID,
        clientSecret: nil,
        keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName,
        delegate: self,
        finishedSelector: #selector(viewController(vc:finishedWithAuth:error:))
    )
}

// Handle completion of the authorization process, and update the Gmail API
// with the new credentials.
func viewController(vc : UIViewController,
                    finishedWithAuth authResult : GTMOAuth2Authentication, error : NSError?) {

    if let error = error {
        service.authorizer = nil
        showAlert(title: "Authentication Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    service.authorizer = authResult
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Helper for showing an alert
func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
    )
    let ok = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
        handler: nil
    )
    alert.addAction(ok)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

btnSyncGmail button action

```
@IBAction func startSyncingGmail(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let authorizer = service.authorizer,
        let canAuth = authorizer.canAuthorize , canAuth {
        fetchLabels()
    } else {
        present(
            createAuthController(),
            animated: true,
            completion: nil
        )
    }

    output.frame = view.bounds
    output.isEditable = false
    output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
    output.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

    view.addSubview(output);

    if let auth = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.authForGoogleFromKeychain(
        forName: kKeychainItemName,
        clientID: kClientID,
        clientSecret: nil) {
        service.authorizer = auth
    }
}
```

I run the app; after tapping the button, loader started after few seconds I am getting "HTTP 403 forbidden" access error as output. I am not getting why I am getting this. Did I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

The 403 Forbidden error is due to a scoping error, try to double check if you use the correct scope. Check this [Gmail scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) to know the description of each scope. Use this `https://mail.google.com/` scope to have complete or full access in the Gmail API. Also, don't forget to enable the Gmail API and the other API you are using in the Dev Console.

Comment: I checked in Dev Console, Gmail API is enabled and I tried the scope value you mentioned but I am getting same 403 Forbidden error